# "DD/MM/YYYY - HH:SS" para "milliseconds"

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou utilizando o `datetimepicker` do Bootstrap e preciso converter o resultado para "milliseconds".

Atualmente o resultado sai: "dd/mm/yyyy - hh:ss" e preciso dele em "milliseconds".

Qual a melhor forma?

Answer (score 3):

Basta usar o método `getDate`, ou qualquer um dos eventos, como o `changeDate`, para recuperar em formato `Date`, em vez de pegar a *string* formatada.

Depois, basta aplicar o `.getTime()`:

```
$('#time').datetimepicker().on('changeDate', function (e) {
    // Aqui você tem o resultado em ms sem precisar fazer o parse manual:
    e.date.getTime();
});
```

Veja funcionando no **[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bacco/vf4uudxy/)**.

Answer (score 1):

```
var dateString = $('21/09/2014 - 18:22'),
    dateArgs = dateString.match(/\d{2,4}/g),
    year = dateArgs[2],
    month = dateArgs[1],
    day = dateArgs[0],
    hour = dateArgs[3],
    minutes = dateArgs[4];
milliseconds = new Date(year, month, day, hour, minutes).getTime();
```